# Is NSUserDefaults the correct place to store a list of favorites?

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, favorite

I am programming an app for iOS, allowing the user to make connections via tcp/ip. The user is able to save a server as a favorite. To make this possible I am serialising the server object and storing it to the NSUserDefaults.

Is this the correct way to go or should I rather save the serialised object to the file system?

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSUserDefaults' data is also stored on the filesystem.
Don't try to re-invent the wheel. It's here on purpose, and it's very easy and convenient to use. : )

Comment: Thanks :) I guess I was a little suspicious because it was so easy :-D And in the apple docs they just talk about settings and the like.